# Port ownership when accessing an Internet address

Tags: networking, internet, ip, connection, port

Let's say we're accessing the google.com:443 server. Port 443 is used here, is it an internal port that is issued by the operating system to the google server, or is it the port of the router that, having received our message, redirects it to some other internal port of the google server?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's say we're accessing the google.com:443 server. Port 443 is used here, is it an internal port that is issued by the operating system to the google server, or is it the port of the router that, having received our message, redirects it to some other internal port of the google server?

"Traditionally" it's the former, but in practice it could be either, and you have no way to know which.

For simple services, it is usually the webserver *itself* that has a 'public' IP address and listens on port 443 – the routers are completely transparent and just route packets without modification. That's the "standard" way of hosting services.

However, some servers *do* use NAT – it could be either 1:1 NAT (where the router translates the IP address to a private one but doesn't touch ports at all), like at various Large Cloud Providers which use this for 'floating IPs', *or* it could be specific "port forwarding" NAT that translates addresses and ports, like when people host websites on their home connection (e.g. someone.dyndms.com:8001 could be forwarded to 192.168.1.7:80 internally).

Comment: OK, thank you so much